# How to run nosetests in a project using Cython

Tags: python, cython, python-3.3, distutils, nosetests

I have a project structure like:

```
pgmpy/
|-- pgmpy
|   |-- BayesianModel
|   |   |-- BayesianModel.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- Exceptions
|   |   |-- Exceptions.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- Factor
|   |   |-- CPD.py
|   |   |-- _factor_product.c
|   |   |-- _factor_product.pyx
|   |   |-- Factor.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- Independencies
|   |   |-- Independencies.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- MarkovModel
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- MarkovModel.py
|   |-- readwrite
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- ProbModelXML.py
|   `-- tests
|       |-- help_functions.py
|       |-- test_BayesianModel.py
|       `-- test_Independencies.py
`-- setup.py
```

The Factor dir contains a .pyx file. When I install pgmpy using setup.py it compiles with Cython and creates a shared object file in python's dist-packages dir. But since this shared object file is not available in the project dir, running `nosetests` from this dir gives an error that it is unable to import the cython file. Running nosetests from any other directory works fine.

What should I do to make sure that nosetests runs from the project dir also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at your project, try changing the import of `setup` from `distutils.core` into just `setuptools`, as `distutils` does not provide useful functionality such as `python setup.py develop` - this will instead build the .so file into `pgmpy/Factor/_factor_product.cpython-33m.so` which will then be available for import.

Comment: Does that mean change `from distutils.core import setup` into `import setuptools` in setup.py?

Comment: `from setuptools import setup`.